# How to store webpage link values in combobox, then go to that link when user selects in combobox

Tags: vb.net, combobox, html

What I am trying to do is have a webbrowser get links from a website, store them in a combobox, and when the user selects that link (link text) is goes to the link in the browser.

So far I can get the link text and store it in the combobox. In the 2 examples below when I run it, and uncomment out the msgbox, the strings match but for some reason the if statement never evaluates as true.

HTML CODE:

```
<span title="Changes - Stored in Combobox" class="Changes - info">
         <a href="/Goto_this_link_if_selected/">Changes - Stored in Combobox</a>
'</span>
```

My Code-
I have tried:

```
Private Sub ComboBoxSelectAppName_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As _ EventArgs) Handles ComboBoxSelectAppName.SelectedIndexChanged
   Dim ComboSelect As String
   Dim theElementCollection As HtmlElementCollection
   comboSelect = ComboBoxSelectAppName.SelectedItem.ToString()
   theElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span")
   For Each curElement As HtmlElement In theElementCollection
     ' MsgBox(curElement.GetAttribute("outerTEXT").ToString() & "-" & AppSelect)
     'If curElement.GetAttribute("outerHTML").Contains("title") Then
     ' This works but it sometimes, but grabs the wrong one sometimes if similar
     if curElement.GetAttribute("outerHTML").Equals("title") Then
       If (curElement.GetAttribute("outerHTML") = AppSelect) Then
           MsgBox("Here")
           'WebBrowser1.Navigate(linkElementString)
           'curElement.InvokeMember("click")
        End If
     End If
   Next
End Sub
```

I have also tried This:

```
Private Sub ComboBoxSelectAppName_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As _ EventArgs) Handles ComboBoxSelectAppName.SelectedIndexChanged
 Dim AppSelect As String
 Dim theElementCollection As HtmlElementCollection
 AppSelect = ComboBoxSelectAppName.SelectedItem.ToString()
 theElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.Links
 For Each curElement As HtmlElement In theElementCollection
    'MsgBox(curElement.GetAttribute("outerTEXT").ToString() & "-" & AppSelect)
    If curElement.GetAttribute("outerTEXT").ToString().Contains(AppSelect) Then
      MsgBox("Here")
      'linkElementString = curElement.GetAttribute("innerHTML").ToString()
      'WebBrowser1.Navigate(linkElementString)
      'curElement.InvokeMember("click")          
    End If
 Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I have also tried: If curElement.GetAttribute("outerTEXT") = (AppSelect) Then. the contains does not work because of similar items. Ex. test  and test 1234 would both evaluate to true. I am just frustrated because I though this would have been a simple thing but I spent 4 days trying everything and searching the net to no avail.

Comment: Ok, it took me a few more hours and some sleep but I figured it out. The combobox string had an extra blank space at the end of it. I failed to see the blank space when in the message box so of-course the If statement would not evaluate at true because both strings were not that same.